# maven wsimport throwing security exception with PKIX path building failed:

Tags: web-services, glassfish, java-ee-7

I have an ejb which is annotated with @Webserivce. Everything in glassfish4.

The wsdl is generated correctly, soapUi can also send requests.

But when I try to generate client artifacts using jax ws maven plugin  which is configured as following.

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
              <wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlFile>transactionService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
              </wsdlFiles>
              <packageName>com.me.backend.connector.ws</packageName>
              <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/main/java</sourceDestDir>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I get  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:

So I need to know

1. How can I tell jax ws plugin to use the certificates ?
2. How can I get the certificates, currently the webservice and the client are both on localhost for development purpose
3. How can I tell glassfish4 not to use https and use http when exposing the webservice ?

Comment: Just noticed. Glassfish generates both http and https wsdl locations. So the http one works.

Comment: It would be still nice to know how to give custom certificate to glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed. Glassfish generates both http and https wsdl locations. So the http one works